# Uploading image in cropper js gives error Refused loading image violates Content Security Policy directive: "img-src * data:"

Tags: javascript, .net, google-chrome, content-security-policy, cropperjs

I am using cropperjs to crop an image on image upload [check the button here](https://prnt.sc/vuzqfn)

After selecting the image to upload there is this [issue](https://prnt.sc/vuzrri)

The blob storage data is intact just there is issue after uploading the image
[https://prnt.sc/vuzven\](https://prnt.sc/vuzven%5C)
https://prnt.sc/vuzvnw

`Uploading image in cropper js gives error Refused to load the image 'blob:http://localhost:15536/0b13fa91-8bd8-40f2-a3c1-9aed987713ee' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src * data:".`

Any solution on this why this is not working on google chrome. Same issue in firefox and every other browser

Answer (score -1):

Just add the `blob:` scheme to the policy: `img-src * data: blob:`